# Pulling values/text from dropdown menu

Tags: javascript, html

I am working on an assignment for a javascript course, to have a user input a name and make a selection from a dropdown menu, then click a button to add the input/selection to a map, then click another button to display the map data.  After writing the code, I can enter the name and make the selection, but clicking the buttons doesn't do anything.  Tried debugging, and I keep getting weird errors.  The newest error is in the line declaring ADDBUTTON, saying document.getElementByID isn't a function.  I have also been getting an error in the ADDBUTTON.onclick block that I can't assign a null variable.

Does anyone have any thoughts?

```
...

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    <head>
        <title>Camp Whack-a-Doo Chore List</title>
    </head>

    <body>
    
        <h1>Add to the Chore List</h1>
        
        <p>Enter the Camper's name and their assigned chore, then click the Add button.
        Click the Display button to view the list.</p>
        
        <label for = "name">Camper Name</label>
        <input type = "text" id = "name" /><br/>
        
        <label for = "chore">Choose a Chore</label>
        <select id = "chore">
            
            <option value = "frontSweep">Front Room Sweep</option>
            <option value = "backSweep">Back Room Sweep</option>
            <option value = "outsideGrounds">Outside Grounds</option>
            <option value = "toilet">Clean Toilet</option>
            <option value = "sink">Clean Sink</option>
            <option value = "trashSupplies">Trash Patrol and Supplies</option>
            
        </select><br/>
        
        <button id = "btnToAddToCL">Add to Chore List</button>
        <button id = "btnToDisplayCL">Display Chore List</button>
        
        <div id = "result"></div>
        
    <script>
    
    const ADDBUTTON = document.getElementByID('btnToAddToCL');
    const DISPLAYBUTTON = document.getElementByID('btnToDisplayCL');
    
    let choreList = new Map();
    
    ADDBUTTON.onclick = function(){
    
        let name = document.getElementByID('name');
        
        let c = document.getElementByID('chore').value;
        let chore = c.target.options[c.selectedIndex].text;
        
        choreList.set(name.value, chore.value);
        
        name.value = "";
        chore.value = "";
    
    };
    
    DISPLAYBUTTON.onclick = function(){
    
        let out = "";
        
        for(let x of choreList.entries()){
        
            out += x[0] + ": " + x[1];
            out += "<br/>";
        
        }
        
        document.getElementByID('result').innerHTML = out;
    
    }
    
    </script>
    
    </body>

</html>
...
```

Comment: `document.getElementByID isn't a function`...yep, it's `document.getElementById`. JS is case-sensitive. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById . See also [this](https://www.google.com/search?q=document.getelementbyid+is+not+a+function) - much easier to find the answer that way.

Comment: `error in the ADDBUTTON.onclick block that I can't assign a null variable`...please always paste the exact error message. Don't abbreviate, paraphrase or make any other changes, Then there is no ambiguity. Also, ensure the information you provide tells us exactly which line it occurs on. Saying it's within a particular block is not precise enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check this snippet, I have corrected syntax errors and now it is working.

What was wrong?

`document.getElementByID` should be `document.getElementById`

`document.getElementById('chore').value` should be just `document.getElementById('chore')` as in this situation you the need the whole element object not just the value.

`c.tagrets.options[c.selectedIndex].text;` should be just `c.options[c.selectedIndex].text;` as `c` itself is the target.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    <head>
        <title>Camp Whack-a-Doo Chore List</title>
    </head>

    <body>
    
        <h1>Add to the Chore List</h1>
        
        <p>Enter the Camper's name and their assigned chore, then click the Add button.
        Click the Display button to view the list.</p>
        
        <label for = "name">Camper Name</label>
        <input type = "text" id = "name" /><br/>
        
        <label for = "chore">Choose a Chore</label>
        <select id = "chore">
            
            <option value = "frontSweep">Front Room Sweep</option>
            <option value = "backSweep">Back Room Sweep</option>
            <option value = "outsideGrounds">Outside Grounds</option>
            <option value = "toilet">Clean Toilet</option>
            <option value = "sink">Clean Sink</option>
            <option value = "trashSupplies">Trash Patrol and Supplies</option>
            
        </select><br/>
        
        <button id = "btnToAddToCL">Add to Chore List</button>
        <button id = "btnToDisplayCL">Display Chore List</button>
        
        <div id = "result"></div>
        
    <script>
    
    const ADDBUTTON = document.getElementById('btnToAddToCL');
    const DISPLAYBUTTON = document.getElementById('btnToDisplayCL');
    
    let choreList = new Map();
    
    ADDBUTTON.onclick = function(){
    
        let name = document.getElementById('name');
        
        let c = document.getElementById('chore');
        let chore = c.options[c.selectedIndex].text;
        
        choreList.set(name.value, chore);
        
        name.value = "";
        chore.value = "";
    
    };
    
    DISPLAYBUTTON.onclick = function(){
    
        let out = "";
        
        for(let x of choreList.entries()){
        
            out += x[0] + ": " + x[1];
            out += "<br/>";
        
        }
        
        document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = out;
    
    }
    
    </script>
    
    </body>

</html>
```

Comment: A good quality answer would explain specifically what you have changed and - mostly important - why you changed it. Don't leave it to guesswork, and don't encourage blind copy-pasting culture without learning. That would get you an upvote...

Comment: @ADyson Thanks :)
I have updated my answer with what was wrong in the source code. Please help me with the upvote.

Comment: Oh man, I figured it was something stupid that I couldn't see.  I appreciate the fresh set of eyes and the assistance!

Comment: @Kayla Please do upvote and mark as complete answer as you got the solution.

Answer (score 0):

## Almost Perfect

So I just went over some of the case spelling of "getElementById" and corrected and used your idea of setting variables of the elements prior to running the code.

How I debugged this was I commented out all of the things and uncommented one at a time testing things using `console.log(value)` to see if I was able to get a value.

This is a running version.

```js
    const ADDBUTTON = document.getElementById('btnToAddToCL');
    const DISPLAYBUTTON = document.getElementById('btnToDisplayCL');
    const CHORES = document.getElementById('chore');
    const NAME = document.getElementById('name');
    
    const choreList = new Map();
    
    ADDBUTTON.onclick = function() {
    
        console.log('add button click')
        
        const camper = NAME.value;
        const chore = CHORES.options[CHORES.selectedIndex].text;
        
        choreList.set(camper, chore);
        
        NAME.value = "";
        CHORES.selectedIndex = 0;
    };

    DISPLAYBUTTON.onclick = function(){
    
        let out = "";
        
        for(let x of choreList.entries()){
        
            out += x[0] + ": " + x[1];
            out += "<br/>";
        
        }
        
        document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = out;
    
    }
```

```html
        <h1>Add to the Chore List</h1>
        
        <p>Enter the Camper's name and their assigned chore, then click the Add button.
        Click the Display button to view the list.</p>
        
        <label for = "name">Camper Name</label>
        <input type = "text" id = "name" /><br/>
        
        <label for = "chore">Choose a Chore</label>
        <select id = "chore">
            
            <option value = "frontSweep">Front Room Sweep</option>
            <option value = "backSweep">Back Room Sweep</option>
            <option value = "outsideGrounds">Outside Grounds</option>
            <option value = "toilet">Clean Toilet</option>
            <option value = "sink">Clean Sink</option>
            <option value = "trashSupplies">Trash Patrol and Supplies</option>
            
        </select><br/>
        
        <button id = "btnToAddToCL">Add to Chore List</button>
        <button id = "btnToDisplayCL">Display Chore List</button>
        
        <div id = "result"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the assistance!  I figured it was something stupid that I just wasn't seeing.

Comment: u should checkout react